# CDI Injection raises "WELD-001408" for multimodule project

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, jboss6.x, weld

I have a project with some web artifacts (.war) and I'm facing problems to Inject simple POJOs. The following code represents the simplest working case:

**.war (WAR1)**

```
public class MyManagedBean {
    @Inject
    private MyPojo myPojo;   
}
```

**POJO in .war (WAR1)**

```
public class MyPojo {
    public void doSomething() {}
}
```

The problem occurs when I add one more web artifact (.war --> WAR2) with the same POJO (MyPojo) packaged. Semantically I want my POJO in each web artifact, not an external archive (.jar).  Basically the newest added component (WAR2) is identical to WAR1, i.e., it simulates as if it existed a multimodule project. At runtime, container raises the following error when trying to use a module:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MyPojo] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.projectx.MyManagedBean.myPojo]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:270) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionTarget(Validator.java:299) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetValidator.addInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetValidator.java:34) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1055) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireProcessInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1249) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.integration.injection.Jsr299SimpleNonContextualInjector.inject(Jsr299SimpleNonContextualInjector.java:66) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.injection.manager.core.DefaultInjectionContext.proceed(DefaultInjectionContext.java:58) [:1.0.0-alpha-7]
at org.jboss.injection.manager.core.DefaultInjectionManager.inject(DefaultInjectionManager.java:58) [:1.0.0-alpha-7]
at org.jboss.injection.manager.core.DefaultInjectionManager.inject(DefaultInjectionManager.java:64) [:1.0.0-alpha-7]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processInjectors(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:410) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection.JBossDelegatingInjectionProvider.inject(JBossDelegatingInjectionProvider.java:77) [:1.0.3]
... 66 more
```

Some scenarios details:

1. If I remove WAR2, the injection made by WAR1 starts to work.
2. Both of artifacts (WAR1 and WAR2) have the same POJOs and beans.xml (/WEB-INF).

Is there any point am I missing? All I need is the possibility to inject a class, like a "*.Helper" for example. As I know, CDI allows to Inject even primitive types.

- JDK 1.7
- JBoss 6.1.0
- Weld 1.1.Beta2

Comment: Which dependencies are not being satisfied?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's "myPojo" attribute in "MyManagedBean".

Comment: Are you deploying your war directly on the server or are they packaged in an EAR ?

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand it's being deployed in an expanded EAR.

Comment: I didn't payed attention to your tech stack, but when you write JBoss 6.1.0 it's JBoss AS not EAP? If it's AS, please migrate to JBoss 7.1.1 since version 6 is very buggy (especially regarding class loading which is certainly related with your issue) and was abandoned in favor of AS 7.x.

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand thanks for disposing your time. I'm actually with JBoss 6.1.0 AS and due to a legacy system architecture and the impossibility to migrate to JBoss 7, I will try to overwrite Weld version and check if it works.

Comment: I understand but you should know that nobody use this version in community, so it will be hard to get some support for it. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand just tried Glassfish and Weld worked like a charm. You're right, it's a matter o version. Really thanks!

Comment: @axcdnt more of problem with JBoss version than Weld in fact.

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand just tried Glassfish for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately using `JBoss 6.1.0 AS` packaged with `Weld 1.1.Beta2` really doesn't work. As a test, tried the same implementation with `Glassfish 3.1.2` and `CDI` injection worked like a charm.

Comment: It would do the same with JBoss AS 7.1.1